# MySQL join multiple columns from same table

Tags: mysql, join, multiple-columns

I am trying to write a query that returns a users profile information, along with a count of occurrences of the user's ID in 2 columns from another table. An example below:

```
TableA
userID  userName
1       UserA
2       UserB

TableB
LinkID  leadID  followID
1       1       2
2       1       3
3       2       1
```

Querying against UserID 1 I would expect to retrieve **UserA**, **2** (occurences of 1 in leadID), and **1** (occurences of 1 in followID). Any help with this is much appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need to join for this - you can instead make three separate selects.

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT userName
    FROM TableA
    WHERE userID = 1
) AS userName,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM TableB
    WHERE leadID = 1
) AS count_leadID,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM TableB
    WHERE followID = 1
) AS count_followID
```

Result:

```
userName  count_leadID  count_followID
UserA     2             1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.userName,
       SUM(IF(b.leadId = a.userId, 1, 0) as Leads,
       SUM(IF(b.followId = a.userId, 1, 0) as Follows
FROM TableA a
     TableB b
GROUP BY a.userName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.userName,
       b1.count(*) as leads,
       b2.count(*) as follows
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b1 on a.userID = b1.leadID
INNER JOIN TableB b2 on a.userID = b2.followID
GROUP BY a.userName
```

Depending on how mySQL optimizes and if you have an index on leadID and followID then this could speed up the query, especially if you're going to query just a few users rather than them all at the same time.

Comment: I get syntax errors with this query, Jeff. I believe I did something similar earlier and it returned the same value for both leads and follows - which is incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, you would, that was a dumb mistake. But using the same SUMs that Mike uses above instead of using counts like I stupidly did should work.